# Post build script for multi-configuration project

Tags: jenkins, multi-configuration

I run a multi-configuration project in jenkins that does several different builds, I would like to run a script when all the sub-configuration/builds are finished.

Is there any thing like a PostBuild action for a multi-configuration job in Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

The [PostBuildScript plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PostBuildScript+Plugin) should do what you need - make sure to get the latest version since older versions had a bug that would run the script after every execution of the multi-config build.